# Optional nodes in a path?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to write a query where I get the :LIKES relationships.

```
  (:USER)
     |
 [:CREATED]
     |
  (:POST)<-[:LIKES]-(:USER)
     | 
[:RESHARED]  
     |
  (:POST)<-[:LIKES]-(:USER)
```

I was trying something along the lines of:

```
MATCH (u:USER {name: "Lamoni"})-[:CREATED]-(p:POST)
OPTIONAL MATCH p<-[:LIKES]-(u2:USER)
OPTIONAL MATCH p<-[:RESHARED]-(p2:POST)<-[:LIKES]-(u3:USER)
```

Any ideas on an optimal way to do this and be able to order them by a property called created_at in a descending order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the `POST` structure always looks like this you can try:

```
// match the whole user-post-post path
MATCH (u:USER {name: "Lamoni"})-[:CREATED]-(p_direct:POST)-[:RESHARED]-(p_shared:Post)
WITH u, p_direct, p_shared
OPTIONAL MATCH (p_direct)<-[:LIKES]-(u2:USER)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p_shared)<-[:LIKES]-(u3:USER)
RETURN u.name, p_direct.xyz, collect(u2.name), p_shared.xyz, collect(u3.name)
```

If you just want all `USERS` that like a `POST` by a given `USER` (independent of the type of `POST`, created or shared) you can also collect all `POST`:

```
MATCH (u:USER {name: "Lamoni"})-[:CREATED|RESHARED*1..2]-(p:Post)
WITH u, p
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:LIKES]-(u2:USER)
WITH u.name, p, u2
ORDER BY u2.created_at
RETURN u.name, p, collect(u2.name)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin,

Is it possible to get all downstram Likes as well for a user, e.g. if User1 posts POST1, and then POST1 is shared by User2, and then User3 LIKES POST1, is it possible to get that LIKE as well (a post could be shared n-amount of times).

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can extend the `[:CREATED|RESHARED*1..10]` match. But if the `POST` can be shared n times, you can end up with very long redundant lists of the same `POST` with `RESHARED` relationships. It would make a lot more sense to model this differently but that is a different question.